# How to show connection line in d3.js map ('Error: <path> attribute d: Expected number)

Tags: javascript, d3.js

"I'm making a world map with a orange connecting line between certain coordinates on the map using d3.js
like this
https://www.d3-graph-gallery.com/graph/connectionmap_basic.html

[current map picture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GobmY.png)

There is no problem showing the map, but orange line connecting Otawa and Brasilia doesn't appear on the map, with error

"
Error:  attribute d: Expected number, "…7.6843192758206,NaNL-148.3185307…".
"

on d3.v4.js:1206

And I have no idea why the error occurs since I think I put correct coordinate inputs.

I already searched for this error messages, but I couldn't solve the problem since most of them are about d3 graph problems, not a map.

And I tried using many kinds of inputs for coordinates, but all of them didn't work.

(this is a script in jsp file, and I'm using this jsp in Spring Framework)

```
const width = 960,
            height = 500,
            projection = d3.geoMercator()
                .center([0, 5])
                .scale(200)
                .rotate([-180, 0]),
            svg = d3.select('#map').append('svg')
                .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMinYMin meet")
                .attr("viewBox", "0 0 960 500"),
            path = d3.geoPath()
                .projection(projection),
            g = svg.append('g'),
            cities = [{ 'code': 'OTT', 'city': 'OTTAWA', 'country': 'CANADA', 'lat': '23.10', 'lon': '120.34' }, { 'code': 'BSB', 'city': 'BRASILIA', 'country': 'BRAZIL', 'lat': '-32.85', 'lon': '133.30' }, { 'code': 'DEL', 'city': 'DELHI', 'country': 'INDIA', 'lat': '4.71', 'lon': '-127.57' }, { 'code': 'CMX', 'city': 'CIDADE DO MEXICO', 'country': 'MEXICO', 'lat': '0.42', 'lon': '93.19' }, { 'code': 'SID', 'city': 'SIDNEY', 'country': 'AUSTRALIA', 'lat': '-48.38', 'lon': '-71.71' }, { 'code': 'TOK', 'city': 'TOQUIO', 'country': 'JAPAO', 'lat': '17.34', 'lon': '-81.73' }, { 'code': 'CCA', 'city': 'CIDADE DO CABO', 'country': 'AFRICA DO SUL', 'lat': '-43.20', 'lon': '-171.97' }, { 'code': 'CMP', 'city': 'CAMPO GRANDE', 'country': 'BRASIL', 'lat': '-36.15', 'lon': '130.72' }, { 'code': 'PAR', 'city': 'PARIS', 'country': 'FRANCA', 'lat': '22.19', 'lon': '174.27' }, { 'code': 'NOY', 'city': 'NOVA YORK', 'country': 'USA', 'lat': '11.23', 'lon': '112.96' }]

        g.append('image')
            .attr('xlink:href', 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/80/World_map_-_low_resolution.svg')
            .append('path')
            .attr('d', path)

        // Carregar cidades | load city
        //d3.json('cities.json', (error, data) => {
        const circles = g.selectAll('circle')
            .data(cities)
            .enter()
            .append('a')
            .attr('xlink:href', d => 'https://www.google.com/search?q=${d.city}'
            )
            .append('circle')
            .attr('cx', d => projection([d.lon, d.lat])[0])
            .attr('cy', d => projection([d.lon, d.lat])[1])
            .attr('r', 5)
            .style('fill', 'red'),
            drag_handler = d3.drag()
                .on('start', drag_start)
                .on('drag', drag_drag)

        // Change these data to see ho the great circle reacts
        var link = {type: "LineString", coordinates: [[Number(cities[0]["lat"]), Number(cities[0]["lon"])], [Number(cities[1]["lat"]), Number(cities[1]["lon"])]]}

        // I tried many other coordinates input like
        // var link = {type: "LineString", coordinates: [[23.10, 120.34], [-32.85, 133.30]]}
        // but all of them didn't work.




        // Add the path
    svg.append("path")
      .attr("d", path(link))
      .style("fill", "none")
      .style("stroke", "orange")
      .style("stroke-width", 7)

        function drag_start() {
            start_x = +d3.event.x
            start_y = +d3.event.y
        }

        function drag_drag(d) {
            //Get the current scale of the circle 
            //case where we haven't scaled the circle yet
            // get lon x lat
            console.log('lon x lat', projection.invert([d3.event.x, d3.event.y]))

            d3.select(this)
              .attr('cx', d.x = d3.event.x).attr('cy', d.y = d3.event.y)
        }

        drag_handler(circles)

        // zoom and pan
        const zoom = d3.zoom()
            .on('zoom', () => {
                g.style('stroke-width', `${1.5 / d3.event.transform.k}px`)
                g.attr('transform', d3.event.transform) // updated for d3 v4
            })

        svg.call(zoom)
```

I expect an orange line connecting Otawa(Canada) and Brasilia(Brazil) to appear, but the line doesn't appear with error

"
Error:  attribute d: Expected number, "…7.6843192758206,NaNL-148.3185307…".
"

on d3.v4.js:1206

this error occurs at the line

```
// Add the path
   svg.append("path")
       .attr("d", path(link))  // here the error occurs
       .style("fill", "none")
       .style("stroke", "orange")
       .style("stroke-width", 7)
```

while adding the path.

Since path(link) contains NaNL, there might be a problem on variable link, but I have no idea why since I think I correctly put coordinates input like the working code at
https://www.d3-graph-gallery.com/graph/connectionmap_basic.html

Comment: Check the values provided by the `link` variable: does it contain valid coordinates in the projection space? Sometimes if the coordinates provided are out of range it will overflow and return `NaN`.

Comment: you have latitude then longitude: `coordinates: [[Number(cities[0]["lat"]), Number(cities[0]["lon"])]`. But geojson is longitude then latitude.

Comment: Oh my, that was the problem. Now the code works well.

Thank you all  Andrew and Terry.

You saved my days.